# Deserialize XML does not populate array

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have the XML Below and the C# Code. The array of Childconainer's is not being deserialized?
I expect to get a list of them but i get 0.

**C# Class and deserialize method**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace MESMsgTester
{
    public class BscLineageResponse
    {

        public class BSCLineageResponse
        {
            public mes_message mes_message { get; set; }
        }

        public class mes_message
        {
            public string msg_environment { get; set; }
            public msg_header msg_header { get; set; }
            public msg_body msg_body { get; set; }
            public msg_error msg_error { get; set; }
        }

        public class msg_body
        {
            public Container Container { get; set; }
            public ChildContainer[] ChildContainer { get; set; }


        }

        public class msg_header
        {
            public string msg_type { get; set; }
            public int msg_stat { get; set; }
            public string msg_source { get; set; }
            public string msg_time { get; set; }
            public string plant_id { get; set; }
            public string msg_description { get; set; }
            public string msg_string { get; set; }
        }


        public class Container
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }            
        }

        public class ChildContainer
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Level { get; set; }
        }


        public class TaskList
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Revision { get; set; }
            public bool Optional { get; set; }
            public TaskItem TaskItem { get; set; }
        }

        public class TaskItem
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Instruction { get; set; }
            public bool IsTlc { get; set; }
        }

        public class msg_error
        {
            public string error_source { get; set; }
            public string error_code { get; set; }
            public string error_string { get; set; }
        }

        public static BSCLineageResponse ReadBSCLineageResponse(string input)
        {
            BSCLineageResponse result = new BSCLineageResponse();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mes_message));

            // Deserialize XML string into a class object
            result.mes_message = (mes_message)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(input));

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <mes_message>
  <msg_environment>UUUUU</msg_environment> 
- <msg_header>
  <msg_type>VscLineageResponse</msg_type> 
  <msg_stat>1</msg_stat> 
  <msg_source>M590</msg_source> 
  <msg_time>2014/10/23 09:37:44</msg_time> 
  <msg_description /> 
  <msg_string>Inquiry completed successfully</msg_string> 
  </msg_header>
- <msg_body>
- <Container>
  <Name>70145862</Name> 
  </Container>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>MEDMESC-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>500503-002</Name> 
  <Revision>D</Revision> 
  <Description>XXX</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>YYY</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>2</Status> 
  <Qty>0</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>2016/11/22</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/10/21 11:52:29</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>Bay2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>354325-001</Name> 
  <Revision>D</Revision> 
  <Description>Bay SHIPPING OUTER</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1171275900</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>1</Status> 
  <Qty>34</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/08/06 11:32:18</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>Base-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>354337-001</Name> 
  <Revision>B</Revision> 
  <Description>Base SHIPPING INNER Bay NXTDS</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1170654400</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>1</Status> 
  <Qty>34</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/08/06 11:32:18</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>Base2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>354338-001</Name> 
  <Revision>C</Revision> 
  <Description>Base SHIPPING OUTER Bay NXTDS</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1170778400</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>2</Status> 
  <Qty>0</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/10/02 10:36:04</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>TOR2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>357428-101</Name> 
  <Revision>L</Revision> 
  <Description>TORQUE WRENCH BI-DIRECT 6628 ORANGE</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1172658800</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>2</Status> 
  <Qty>0</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/10/02 10:48:10</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>   
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>CORET2-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70087213</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>402232-152</Name> 
  <Revision>E</Revision> 
  <Description>HEADER CORE PG DR Part</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>16845435</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>2</Status> 
  <Qty>0</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/10/08 21:04:44</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>SEAP1-CLN0001</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>356909-066</Name> 
  <Revision>Q</Revision> 
  <Description>SEAL PLUG 0.105 TALL RIBBED</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1171928400</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>1</Status> 
  <Qty>16</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>9999/12/30</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/07/23 08:59:41</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
- <ChildContainer>
  <Name>NUSL-CLN0002</Name> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <ParentContainer>70145862</ParentContainer> 
  <RawMaterialFlag>true</RawMaterialFlag> 
- <Product>
  <Name>500324-003</Name> 
  <Revision>J</Revision> 
  <Description>ADHESIVE SLN RBR 6OZ SEMCO</Description> 
  <TestModelNumber /> 
  </Product>
- <MfgOrder>
  <Name /> 
  <VscSWR /> 
  </MfgOrder>
  <VscBatch>1172445300</VscBatch> 
  <VscSerialNumber /> 
  <InRework>false</InRework> 
  <IsInProcess>true</IsInProcess> 
  <IsOnHold>false</IsOnHold> 
  <Status>2</Status> 
  <Qty>0</Qty> 
  <VscProductExpirationDate>2015/06/16</VscProductExpirationDate> 
  <LastCompletionDateGMT>2014/07/24 16:17:41</LastCompletionDateGMT> 
- <TaskList>
  <Name /> 
- <TaskItem>
  <Name /> 
  </TaskItem>
  </TaskList>
  </ChildContainer>
  </msg_body>
  </mes_message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use attributes to specify your elements and attributes. something like this:

```
public class TaskItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instruction { get; set; }
    public bool IsTlc { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("TaskList")]
public class TaskList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    public bool Optional { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("TaskItems")]
    [XmlArrayItem("TaskItem")]
    public List<TaskItem> TaskItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have decorated your properties with XMLAttribute but they are elements in your XML. So, change all XMLAttribute to XmlElement.

you See
[Deserialize XML to Object Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878790/deserialize-xml-to-object-array)