# update object in c# based on condition

Tags: c#

I have this object here:

```
public class ServiceConfig
{
    public List<DatabaseDescriptor> Databases { get; set; }  
}

public class DatabaseDescriptor
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }        
}

public class Table
{  
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("TableName")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

I have

```
public xml.ServiceConfig xmlData { get; set; }
```

How do i update the xmlData DatabaseDescriptors where the name == test i.e
How do i update it?

SERIALIZING BACK TO XML

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xml.ServiceConfig));
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, ServiceConfig);
            }
```

Comment: I don't know what libraries are you using. What are the `using` declarations on the top of your source code?

Comment: @SHiNKiROU i just get the data after serializing, and i need to modify the xmlData

Comment: Do you want to find the instance DatabaseDescriptor with Name=="Test" and updates? Do I understand?

Comment: So you are sarching how to modify objects and write back XML data to file ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Fabio, yes, that's it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if name is unique

```
using System.Linq;


DatabaseDescriptor db = xmlData.Databases.SingleOrDefault(db => db.name == "test");
if (db != null)
{
                //Update db instance
}
```

else

```
    var dbs = xmlData.Databases.Where(db => db.name == "test");

    foreach (DatabaseDescriptor element in dbs)
    {
        // Update elements
    }
```

if you want to serialize/deserialize in xml Databases property you must decorate with [XmlArray],

you see [Deserialize XML does not populate array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525187/deserialize-xml-does-not-populate-array/26525328#26525328)

Comment: Thanks, this looks good :)
Please can you tell me how to serialize my ServiceConfig back to a xml file?, i'm using the xml writer but maybe my cod eis not correct, please see my edit

Comment: What's not correct?  List<DatabaseDescriptor> doesn't come serialized?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DatabaseDescriptor updateObject = xmlData.Databases.FirstOrDefault(_d => _d.Name.Equals("Test"));
if(updateObject != null)
{
    // update what you want to update...
}
```